# How to stop TVirtualStringTree from scrolling back to the top

Tags: delphi

Whenever I click on an item in TVirtualStringTree the tree is scrolled back to the top.
How can I stop it from scrolling?

These are the properties I have set, presumably it the options you are most interested in.

```
  object vtCodeExplr: TVirtualStringTree
    Left = 0
    Top = 50
    Width = 441
    Height = 1336
    HelpContext = 22
    Margins.Left = 5
    Margins.Top = 5
    Margins.Right = 5
    Margins.Bottom = 5
    Align = alClient
    BevelEdges = []
    BevelInner = bvNone
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    BorderStyle = bsNone
    Colors.BorderColor = 15987699
    Colors.DisabledColor = clGray
    Colors.DropMarkColor = 15385233
    Colors.DropTargetColor = 15385233
    Colors.DropTargetBorderColor = 15385233
    Colors.FocusedSelectionColor = 15385233
    Colors.FocusedSelectionBorderColor = 15385233
    Colors.GridLineColor = 15987699
    Colors.HeaderHotColor = clBlack
    Colors.HotColor = clBlack
    Colors.SelectionRectangleBlendColor = 15385233
    Colors.SelectionRectangleBorderColor = 15385233
    Colors.SelectionTextColor = clBlack
    Colors.TreeLineColor = 9471874
    Colors.UnfocusedColor = clGray
    Colors.UnfocusedSelectionColor = 13421772
    Colors.UnfocusedSelectionBorderColor = 13421772
    DefaultNodeHeight = 27
    Header.AutoSizeIndex = 0
    Header.Height = 29
    Header.MainColumn = -1
    Header.MaxHeight = 15000
    Header.MinHeight = 15
    HintMode = hmHint
    Images = vilItemImages16x16
    Indent = 27
    LineStyle = lsSolid
    Margin = 6
    TabOrder = 0
    TabStop = False
    TextMargin = 6
    TreeOptions.PaintOptions = [toShowButtons, toShowRoot, toShowTreeLines, toThemeAware, toUseBlendedImages]
    OnClick = vtCodeExplrClick
    OnCollapsed = vtCodeExplrCollapsed
    OnCompareNodes = vtCodeExplrCompareNodes
    OnDblClick = vtCodeExplrDblClick
    OnExpanded = vtCodeExplrExpanded
    OnFreeNode = vtCodeExplrFreeNode
    OnGetText = vtCodeExplrGetText
    OnGetImageIndex = vtCodeExplrGetImageIndex
    OnGetHint = vtCodeExplrGetHint
    OnInitNode = vtCodeExplrInitNode
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [igPan, igPressAndTap]
    Touch.InteractiveGestureOptions = [igoPanSingleFingerHorizontal, igoPanSingleFingerVertical, igoPanInertia, igoPanGutter, igoParentPassthrough]
    Columns = <>
  end
```

I needed to add more lines in order to get this edit to update.  Hope this is enough.

Comment: What properties have you set for the VST? Post a copy of the section that holds the VST from the text view of your forms .dfm.

Comment: @TomBrunberg See  update

Comment: Thanks John, doesn't ring a bell though. I can only suggest to look closely at the event handlers.

Comment: Just of curiosity, have you found what scrolls your tree to the top?

Comment: @TomBrunberg - Yes, but it wasn't in the event handlers, I was reloading the tree every time I clicked on an item. 'Duh'

Comment: Ouch! Too obvious to be imaginable :) Good it's solved.